# Postgres chooses wrong query plan

Tags: postgresql, indexing, amazon-rds, sql-execution-plan

I have problems with a query that uses a wrong query plan. Because of the non-optimal query plan the query takes almost 20s.

The problem occurs only for a small number of owner_ids. The distribution of the owner_ids is not uniform. The owner_id in the example has 7948 routes. The total number of routes is 2903096.

The database is hosted on Amazon RDS on a server with 34.2 GiB memory, 4vCPU and provisioned IOPS (instance type db.m2.2xlarge). The Postgres version is 9.3.5.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
    route.id, route_meta.name
FROM
    route
INNER JOIN
    route_meta
USING (id)
WHERE
    route.owner_id = 128905
ORDER BY
    route_meta.name
LIMIT
    61

Query plan:    
"Limit  (cost=0.86..58637.88 rows=61 width=24) (actual time=49.731..18828.052 rows=61 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..7934263.10 rows=8254 width=24) (actual time=49.728..18827.887 rows=61 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using route_meta_i_name on route_meta  (cost=0.43..289911.22 rows=2902910 width=24) (actual time=0.016..2825.932 rows=1411126 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using route_pkey on route  (cost=0.43..2.62 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1411126)"
"              Index Cond: (id = route_meta.id)"
"              Filter: (owner_id = 128905)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"Total runtime: 18828.214 ms"
```

If I increase the limit to 100, a better query plan is used. It takes now less then 100ms.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
    route.id, route_meta.name
FROM
    route
INNER JOIN
    route_meta
USING (id)
WHERE
    route.owner_id = 128905
ORDER BY
    route_meta.name
LIMIT
    100

Query plan:
"Limit  (cost=79964.98..79965.23 rows=100 width=24) (actual time=93.037..93.294 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=79964.98..79985.61 rows=8254 width=24) (actual time=93.033..93.120 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: route_meta.name"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 31kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..79649.52 rows=8254 width=24) (actual time=0.039..77.955 rows=7948 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using route_i_owner_id on route  (cost=0.43..22765.84 rows=8408 width=4) (actual time=0.023..13.839 rows=7948 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (owner_id = 128905)"
"              ->  Index Scan using route_meta_pkey on route_meta  (cost=0.43..6.76 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=7948)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = route.id)"
"Total runtime: 93.444 ms"
```

I already tried following things:

- increasing statistics for owner_id (The owner_id in the example is included in the pg_stats)

  ALTER TABLE route ALTER COLUMN owner_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
- reindex owner_id and name
- vacuum analyse
- increased work_mem from 1MB to 16MB
- when I rewrite the query to `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY xxx) AS rn
  ... WHERE rn <= yyy` in a subquery, the specific case is solved. However it
  introduces performance problems with other ownerids.

A similar problem was solved with a combined index, but that seems impossible here because of the different tables.
[Postgres uses wrong index in query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740639/postgres-uses-wrong-index-in-query-plan)

Comment: Setting `random_page_cost` to a lower value (~1.5) often forces index plans to be preferred. As a hack, you could also try to put the complete query into a CTE and apply the limit in the outer query.

Comment: Changing the random_page_cost doesn't change the query plan.The hack with the complete query in a CTE would solve this specific problem, but introduces another one. We have 1 owner_id that is linked to +50% of the routes. For that user the current query plan is fine. @wildplasser

Comment: What's the output of `show shared_buffers;`? See [tuning wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server).

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall' The shared_buffers is 8714392kB

Comment: BTW: wat is the cardinality of `route_meta.name` ? (and: why do you have an index on it?)

Comment: @wildplasser A route can have multiple translations. There is an index on name to sort alphabetical.

Comment: First ordering by name and then picking the top 100 out of 7948 hardly makes any sense to me.

Comment: @wildplasser It doesn't seem logical for me either. I would except that the threshold to use the name index first (instead of the owner_id index) would be a lot higher. Only 0.27% of the routes have that owner_id.

Comment: @wildplasser When I change the random_page_cast to 0.5 the query executes fine, but is doesn't seem a good plan for other queries.

Comment: Very old question, have you solved this ?  You can try using owner_id in the route_meta, then: EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id, name FROM route_meta WHERE owner_id = 128905 ORDER BY name LIMIT 100

Comment: The database is upgraded to 9.4.15. I now can't reproduce the problem anymore.
The problem is of lesser importance for us now since we transferred almost all our searches to Elasticsearch.